# Can I get the source of a hacked Coldfusion template?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We recently had a hacker gain access to our system.  They dumped some Coldfusion templates and included them in random pages on our sites.

The files they dump start with `Allaire Cold Fusion Template` and then contain what appears to be "garbage", but I believe that this is some kind of pre-compiled Coldfusion code.

We've cleared out the hacks, but I saved off the files because I was hoping that there would be some way to de-compile them and maybe make some sense of them.  Although I think the hack is dealt with, I am a little worried about what this code was doing.  (When I looked at the source of a page that included this code, it created no output, so something had to be going on in the background.)

If there isn't a way, that's cool, I just thought I would at least investigate the possibility of seeing what these files were doing.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: They may be files compiled/encrypted with the old `cfencode.exe` utility. http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2007/12/28/Ive-decrypted-my-CFML-templates-and-lost-the-originals-now-what http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2008/01/encrypted-cfml-templates.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, you have awakened some of my "old" brain cells...  Way back when you could encrypt your ColdFusion templates and they could still be run on a ColdFusion server.  This encryption was not very secure as the decrypting algorithm was readily available.  It was/is an easy way to "hide" your code from the unknowing (I guess).

I did a quick Google search and found an old reference to a decrypt function on Adobe's site that may help "crack" that code.  [AB Positive Encrypt and Decrypt](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1007043)  I believe their code would have to be encrypted this way otherwise the ColdFusion server would not be able to read the files either. This download includes the `cfdecrypt.exe` and `cfencode.exe` programs.

If that tool does not work and if I remember correctly, the ColdFusion encryption before CFMX was done using something called `CFCrypt.exe`.  That was an older versions of ColdFusion I think but you can try using that too.  I couldn't find it but I'm sure if you Google for it can be found.

Please post back with your results.  I'm interested to see what they were doing.

Comment: Hm.. I thought the utility was called `cfencode.exe`, not `cfcrypt.exe`? At least back in MX6 anyway ;)

Comment: @Leigh I think you are right.  I believe `cfcrypt.exe` was pre-MX,  ColdFusion 5 and 4.5 (when I started using ColdFusion).  I just didn't know if newer versions of ColdFusion might still be able to run templates encrypted with it.

Comment: I am not sure. Though I have seen references to `cfcrypt`, a quick search of [the 4.5 docs](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/coldfusion/documentation452.html) only mentioned `cfencode`.

Comment: I know CF8 still supported encrypted files (though maybe not via those particular methods). Savvy CMS uses encrypted application.cfm files. Their documentation makes it sound like CF9/10 still support it as well, but I don't have first-hand experience to confirm.

Comment: Thanks, this tool worked great, and now I'm combing through a 1200+ line Coldfusion file full of some scary stuff...

Comment: Cool, glad it worked and glad you found this before they caused too much damage.  If you find anything interesting let us know.

Comment: @jzimmerman2011 I think your bigger concern is not trying to figure out what it does, its how it got up there.  Lock down FTP, check your file upload forms, patch your server, etc....

Comment: That is the first concern, yes. But knowing what it does is also important, as the script may well have opened new security holes.

Comment: if I was in his position, I'd be working on getting a new server setup, and moving my site to it.  I'd make sure that before it went live that my hole was patched, and then I'd sweep the code once or twice and then go live.  I wouldn't attempt to bring the infected server online.  who knows if other things weren't planted there, even non cf-stuff.

Comment: @steve Yes, we are looking into how this happened in the first place, but I wanted to see if anything significant or obvious popped up in that file. There was a recent CF patch we applied to the server that dealt with some kind of exploitation with the CFIDE; we're thinking that the hacker was able to use that before we got the patch on, and we are just now seeing the fruits of his/her labor.

Comment: And, just to let it be known, I'm really a programmer. Me and the Lead Developer where I work kind of got pigeon-holed as "system administrators", but IT is not our strong suit.  Granted, I'm not completely oblivious to IT stuff, but my degree isn't in it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a program out there cfdecrypt that will help you decompile them.  I haven't used it in years, but here is a link I found to a github project:

https://github.com/disccomp/cfdecrypt