# Updating Coldfusion solr collections with a scheduled task

Tags: collections, solr, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

So I'm pretty new to using the Coldfusion solr search (just moved from a CF8 Mac OS X server to a Linux CF9 server), and I'm wondering what the best way to handle automatically updating the collections is. I know scheduled tasks are meant for this but I haven't been able to find any examples online.

I currently have a scheduled task set up to update all of the collections weekly by getting the list of collections and using the cfindex tag in a loop to run the refresh command. This is pretty processing intensive though and takes about ten minutes to update the four collections I have set up so far. This works when I run it in the browser, but I get this error "The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFLOOP" when I run the task from scheduled task administration page.

Is there a better way to handle updating the collections? Would it be better if I made a task to update each collection individually?

Here's my update code.

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="1800">

<cfcollection action="list" name="collections" engine="solr">

<cfloop query="collections">
    <cfindex collection="#name#" action="refresh" extensions=".pdf, .html, .htm, .cfml, .cfm" type="path" key="/home/#name#/public_html/" recurse="yes">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I don't know that there is a better way to do it. As far as your time out when running from the administration page, that is a benign error. The timeout is actually the administration page, not your scheduled task. This happens because the admin page attempts to wait for the scheduled task to finish and has a separate timeout than the page request timeout (and in your case the cfsetting request timeout). If you add some logging to a file in your code you will see that the job actually continues to run.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clearing that up. I just wanted to be sure I was going about this the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier versions of ColdFusion there was a URL parameter that could be passed on any HTTP request to change the server's timeout for the requested page. You might have guessed from the scheduled task configuration that there's an HTTP request running your task, so it functions just like any other page. In those earlier versions you would have just added `&requesttimeout=900` to the URL and that gave the server 15 minutes to process that task.

In later versions they realized that this URL parameter was a security risk but they needed a way to allow developers to declare that an individual HTTP request should still be allowed to take longer than the default page timeout set in the ColdFusion Administrator. So they moved it from the URL parameter to the `<cfsetting>` tag.

```
 <cfsetting requesttimeout="900" />
```

You need to put the cfsetting tag at the top of the page, rather than putting it inside your loop, because it's resetting the total allowable time from the beginning of the request, not just since the last cfsetting tag. Ben Nadel wrote a blog article about that here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/626-CFSetting-RequestTimeout-Updates-Timeouts-It-Does-Not-Set-Them.htm

I'm not sure if there's an upper limit to the request timeout. I do know that in the past when I've had a really long-running task like that, the server has gradually slowed down, in some cases until it crashed. I'm not sure if I would expect reindexing Solr collections to degrade performance so badly, I think my tasks were doing some other things that were probably hogging memory at the time. Anyway if you run into that issue, you may need to divide it up into separate tasks for each collection and just make sure there's enough time between the tasks to allow each one to complete before the next one starts.

EDIT: Oops! I don't know how I missed the `cfsetting` tag in the original question. D'oh! In any event, when you execute a scheduled task via the CF Administrator, it performs a `cfhttp` request to execute the task. This is the way scheduled tasks are normally executed, and I suspect it's so the task can execute inside your own application scope, but the effect is that there are two separate requests executing. I don't think there's a `cfsetting` tag in the CFIDE page, but I suspect a person could add one if they wanted to allow that page longer to wait for the task to complete.

EDIT: Okay, if you wanted to add the `cfsetting` in the CFIDE, you would first have to decrypt the template and then add your one line of code... which might void your warranty on the server, but is probably not dangerous. ;) For decrypting the template see: [Can I get the source of a hacked Coldfusion template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732958/can-i-get-the-source-of-a-hacked-coldfusion-template/14733416#14733416) - and the template to edit is `/CFIDE/administrator/scheduler/scheduletasks.cfm`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do have have the cfsetting tag above my loop, and it does add the necessary time I need for the page to finish processing. The only time it appeared to not be working was in the Coldfusion admin where you can test the scheduled task. Miguel-F pointed out that the Scheduled Task admin page has it's own page time out setting that ignores what is set in the file it is attempting to test. SO essentially that page can time out, but the process it's testing continues to run in the background.

Comment: I'm also curious if there's an upper limit to the request timeout setting, but I haven't had a need to find out.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that... I don't know how I missed that when I first read your question. D'oh! It's not actually that the CF Admin page is ignoring the timeout request, but rather that they're separate requests. The CF Admin page executes a `cfhttp` request when you test the scheduled task, just like the server would execute one when the scheduled task executes normally. My guess is they did it that way so the scheduled task could execute inside your own application scope, but the effect is separate requests. You could probably add a requesttimeout in your cfide page though.

Comment: No worries, and that's not a bad idea. Though I'm too worried about it. I'm happy just knowing that my task was working as intended.

Comment: That's understandable. Thanks for selecting the answer. :)